# When is a raven like an eagle? When it's on the Ravenclaw house crest

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

I saw an image macro on facebook the other day that started me thinking;

[image: Potter confronts Umbridge]

I tried to look into it and I found two separate styles.

## Pottermore Style

[image: Fan-drawn Ravenclaw House crest]

## Book Style

[image: *Deathly Hallows* Hogwarts crest showing Ravenclaw eagle]

Neither of these to me looks anything like a raven, besides being bird shaped.

Is the crest meant to show a raven, or just some sort of bird?

I've struggled to find an 'official' rendition of the crest, and this is the best I could find, but I've seen plenty of fan-mad crests that *do* show a raven, seemingly correcting this 'mistake'.

So why does the Ravenclaw symbol show an eagle, and not a Raven?

Comment: It appears from @Slytherincess' answer that it is intended to be an eagle but I would also point out that the bird in the Pottermore-style crest does look a heck of a lot like all the ravens I have seen, and the bird in the book-style crest looks as much like a raven as it does an eagle (an angry chicken perhaps?).

Comment: In heraldry, a raven and an eagle are not really distinguishable. Generally, if it's displayed (wings out to either side), then it's an eagle, and if it's in profile (especially if it has something in its beak, and/or if it's fuzzy), then it's a raven.

Comment: Gryffindor has a lion as their animal - why don't they have a griffin? Hufflepuff has a badger - why don't they have an out of breath puff?

Comment: Do the books have a textual description of what animal it is?  Or is this solely based on the drawing?

Comment: @b_jonas - It's an eagle. *Goblet of Fire* says: *blue with a bronze eagle for Ravenclaw* in chapter 15, *Beauxbatons and Durmstrang*. :)

Comment: @Slytherincess: thanks, it's there indeed.

Comment: It is very obvious to me (at least) that the bird in the Pottermore crest is a raven based upon the shape of its beak which is very bulky and is more of a "generalist" shape whereas the bird from the book is an eagle based on the hook shape of the beak used for tearing flesh.

Comment: @Pureferret - I really hope you will reconsider this answer, as apparently Pottermore has confirmed Ravenclaw's bird on the crest is an eagle, not a Raven. Your current chosen answer is incorrect. :)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**When is a raven not an eagle?**

When the word raven is describing a color not the bird. It is an easy mistake to make if you are unfamiliar with old world naming conventions.

> ### **Raven**
>
> /ˈrāvən/ -
>
> **Noun:** A large heavily built crow, esp. the all-black common raven (Corvus corax), feeding chiefly on carrion.
>
> **Adjective:** Of a glossy black color
>
> **Verb:** (of a ferocious wild animal) Hunt for prey.
>
> **Synonyms**
>
> - noun: crow - corbie - rook;
> - adjective: black;
> - verb: pillage - loot - maraud - harry - devour

The name of the founder was Rowena Ravenclaw. The raven being described is not a bird that is a raven, but the color of the claw of the bird (an eagle) that is being described. Rowena Ravenclaw gave her name and her standard which included an eagle that is described in its name as raven-clawed. (black colored claws)

[image]

Comment: That's interesting about the color aspect, but I'm not sure why it's applicable to Ravenclaw. Maybe I'm misunderstanding. Black as a color isn't associated with Ravenclaw -- the house colors are either blue and gray/silver or blue and copper (I'm thinking it's blue/silver) ... I'm totally confused. Can you frame it a different way so I can better understand?

Comment: Her name was Ravenclaw. It has nothing to do with house colors. It is merely a naming convention, nothing more. The bird on the standard is most likely an eagle since ravens were more associated with carrion birds. So people are confusing her name with the bird, believing there should be a raven on the standard, not an eagle. Familiarity with heraldry helps understand how this misunderstanding could take place.

Comment: Well, I get what you're saying. In **Dason**'s answer, though, **Martha** says the opposite about heraldry, citing a practice called "punning" which *does* associate an animal with a name if possible. Forget what I said about the house colors -- I was responding to your comments about the color of the talons, but it's irrelevant to the issue of heraldry, which I think is more at issue. :)

Comment: "Raven" the color seems to postdate Rowena Ravenclaw by several hundred years (the OED's first cite for it is in the 17th century). So I find this explanation deeply  unsatisfying. (-1)

Comment: A book written by a modern writer creating a fictional universe overlaying thousands of years of history in a rather lackadaisical and unsystematic fashion and you find MY answer deeply unsatisfying? OED first reference for the English word is 17th century. Earlier versions of the word exist in French and Latin as well, with differing meanings. Punning may also be responsible for those changes as well.

Comment: @Micah I find it amusing you criticize Thaddeus for an English definition not being a valid name for someone born in 993 AD. In Scotland 993, they spoke Old English. Obviously, Ravenclaw (a combination of two post dark ages English words) was not her name, but a *translation* of her name. The OE word for **night** is *nihthræfn*, while the OE word for **claw** is *clifer*. Her name was likely Nihthræfnclifer, or somesuch, meaning Nightclaw. Thaddeus' answer stands just fine as a post-Dark Age English ideologic translation of Nihthræfnclifer.

Comment: Raven descends from the same OE word, as does night. Both would be valid translations, but Raven is closer to the interpretation "dark" as opposed to the possible "time period" interpretation.

Answer (score 16):

The Ravenclaw house crest shows an eagle, [according to Pottermore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIyCd.jpg), because **eagles soar where others cannot climb**.

This is the official eagle image for Ravenclaw from Pottermore:

[image: Eagle emblem - Ravenclaw house crest]

I would pay no attention to the fan-made house crests, aside from enjoying them as fun examples of fan art.

Comment: that is kinda funny because a raven can soar just as good as an eagle... now if they put a turkey vulture on the crest, that would be a different story.

Comment: +1 I'm surprised it's not a raven. Ravens (crows in general) are famed for their very exceptional intelligence so they would be the perfect animal for Ravenclaw. As for soaring where others cannot climb... I thought that kind of greatness belonged to Slytherin.

Comment: @DQdlM Or a real turkey, for that matter. Or a penguin. Ouch! :)

Comment: @commando -- And if I recall correctly, don't ravens collect things? One might take that mean collecting little bits of knowledge here and there and spiriting them away. That kind of image sits well for me for Ravenclaw. Can't argue with you re: Slytherin ;) Thanks for the +1 :)

Comment: @Slytherincess although penguins do soar quite adeptly underwater, but I realize that my comment could have been read 2 ways if one is not familiar with the soaring ability of turkey vultures.  In fact, a turkey vulture can soar much better than an eagle or a raven, so it would have been a better choice to match the slogan.  Turkey vultures have other less admirable characteristics however :)

Comment: @DQdlM - Thanks for the info re: turkey vultures. I once met a turkey vulture name Kurt at the Wild Animal Park in San Diego, California. Not a very glamorous bird, but he put on a good show :)

Comment: The artists behind the Pottermore house crests shared their design process, and they call it an eagle, not a raven: http://insider.pottermore.com/2011/10/behind-scenes-pottermore-house-crests.html

Comment: @alexwlchan -- Which makes complete sense ... wait, it doesn't make sense ... !!!! :)

Comment: I agree. Sometimes the answer is no more complicated than “Rowena Ravenclaw liked eagles more than ravens.”

Answer (score 13):

Why should it show a raven?  The house is named after Rowena Ravenclaw. Sure her name has "raven" in it but I see no reason that Ravenclaw should choose a raven to use as their symbol; just like I see no reason why Brazil should have a bra on their national flag (thankfully they have common sense as well and don't have a bra on their flag).  The eagle is meant to represent that Ravenclaws "soar where others cannot climb" so there is meaning there.  It doesn't seem to be in the nature of Ravenclaw to choose a raven solely because there is a raven in the house name unless there is other meaning they would wish to ascribe to that symbol.

Comment: Heraldry has a concept called *canting*: alluding to or punning on the bearer's name. Thus, it would be totally normal for the Ravenclaw family to have a raven on their arms. In fact, if the arms had a bird on it that was *not* displayed (i.e. not definitely an eagle), then a herald would probably conclude that the bird is meant to be a raven, just based on the name. (This happens a lot in hastily-painted rolls of arms: about all you can tell from the picture is that it's a critter of some sort, and then you see that the name is Brock, so then you conclude that the critter is a badger.)

Comment: Sure.  But saying "Ravenclaw's animal isn't a raven and that doesn't make sense" seems silly to me.  You could allude to Ravenclaw's name by making the symbol a raven.  Or you could use something that makes more sense that actual represents the house itself.  It just seems to me that Rowena Ravenclaw would choose to use a symbol that she felt symbolized the house itself (and canon seems to back that up).

Comment: Except that heraldically speaking, it *doesn't* make sense: if there's an obvious cant available, its very surprising (to put it mildly) to not have that on the arms. And then to have something that is close-but-not-quite? That just smacks of "someone didn't study their heraldry".

Comment: And you're right: Gryffindor *should* have a gold griffin on their arms. Which is just more support for "someone didn't study their heraldry".

Comment: +1. If Ravenclaw thought that an eagle was more representative of her house (or herself) than a raven, she would put an eagle on her crest, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Ravenclaw's symbol is an eagle. It should not be a raven just because the founder for whom the house was named, Rowena Ravenclaw, has that bird in her name.  To demonstrate, no one ever says that the symbol of Gryffindor should be a gryffin instead of a lion.  Why not? Gryffin is in the name Gryffindor, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

In the French translation of Harry Potter the Ravenclaw house is named "Serdaigle" so is Rowena's last name. Serdaigle as "Serre d'aigle" which is the exact translation of "Eagle's claw" in French. If they had translate Ravenclaw in French it would have been "Serdecorbeau" which isn't really aesthetically flattering.

Comment: Interesting note, but this doesn't seem to answer the question of why the symbol is an eagle.

Comment: If anything, the crest as described in the book (blue with a bronze eagle, I can't remember the exact quote) explains the French translator's choice of an eagle, of all bird names that could have sounded good.

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with the Ravenclaw house, one thing that sets them apart is that they LIKE being different. Of course they wouldn't want a raven, just because their house founder's last name was Ravenclaw. That's just silly. C'mon guys, don't you remember Luna Lovegood...?

Comment: Luna Lovegood was weird on her own and irrespective of anybody's opinion. Can you provide any evidence that shows a house-wide desire to be different?

Answer (score 0):

According to Pottermore 
"Our emblem is the eagle, which soars where others cannot climb;"
I think this is the reason why it's an eagle, not raven. I could be wrong.

Answer (score -5):

Ravens are renown for their intelligence.  Which makes perfect sense for the ravenclaw crest.   Gryphons are part lion.  Snakes slither.  And badgers huff and puff.  I say, don't read more into it - it's a book originally written for kids.

Comment: That seems reasonable enough. Has anyone confirmed this, though?

Comment: Except that canon says something completely different